# Modify XMLSchema Location with vtd-xml and xPath

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, vtd-xml

Is there a way to modify the XML schema location parsed by vtd-xml ?

The xml files look like

```
<rootElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="xmlSchema.xsd">
.
.
.
 </rootElement>
```

The best solution would be with xPath. I tried

```
/rootElement/@*
```

which works with DOM but not with vtd-xml

Here is my code

```
String xPath = "/rootElement/@*"
XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier();
VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
if (vg.parseFile(fnIn,true)){
       VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
       xm.bind(vn);
       nodeXpath(xPath,vn);
}

private void nodeXpath(String xPath, VTDNav vn) throws Exception{
    int result;

    AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot();
    ap.selectXPath(xPath);
    ap.bind(vn);
    while((result = ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
    System.out.println(vn.getAttrVal("xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation") + ", " + vn.getText() + ", " + vn.toString(result));
    xm.updateToken(result,"test");
        int p = vn.getText();

        if (p!=-1) {                
            System.out.println(vn.getText() + ", " + vn.toString(p));               
        }
    }
}
```

The result printed to screen is:
10, -1, xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation

and the output xml is

```
test
<rootElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" test="xmlSchema.xsd">
```

The element Name seems to be modified and an additional test is on top?
Where is my mistake? How can I change the attribute value?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you set the namespace awareness of parsefile to false?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think getText() works for attribute value.  Also the output does not seem to make sense either.

Comment: I tried that but nothing changes

Comment: What did u try that isn't working?

Comment: Did you remove getText() and use XPath,s result directly?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to explain. Can you show this on the basis of my code, just the while loop if it is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is my modification of your code. Result is the attribute name token index. And "result+1" should be the attribute value token index. Let me know if it works for you or not.

```
AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot();
ap.selectXPath(xPath);
ap.bind(vn);
while((result = ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
// System.out.println(vn.getAttrVal("xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation") + ", " + vn.getText() + ", " + vn.toString(result));
xm.updateToken(result_+1,"test");
```